# R: If statement for multiple conditions based on list/vector

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Say I have an n-vector that I want to apply an if-condition of based on multiple conditions stored in another vector/list, how can I loop and assign the names to my original vector?

```
set.seed(1234)

# Data
b <- rpois(100, 4)

# Condition
a <- 1:10
names(a) <- paste0(seq(10,100, by = 10),'%')
```

Comment: Edited: I forgot to mention that the condition should be <= interval, not discrete numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
set.seed(1234)

# n-vector
b <- rpois(100, 4)

#  multiple conditions stored in another vector/list 
a <- 1:10
names(a) <- paste0(seq(10,100, by = 10),'%')

# loop and assign the names to the original vector
for(i in unique(a)){
  b <- ifelse(b==i,names(a[a==i]),b)
}
b
```

> ```
>   [1] "20%"  "40%"  "40%"  "40%"  "60%"  "50%"  "0"    "20%"  "50%"  "40%"  "50%"  "40%"  "30%"  "70%"  "30%"  "60%"  "30%"  "30%" 
>  [19] "20%"  "20%"  "30%"  "30%"  "20%"  "10%"  "20%"  "60%"  "40%"  "70%"  "60%"  "10%"  "40%"  "30%"  "30%"  "40%"  "20%"  "50%" 
>  [37] "20%"  "30%"  "100%" "60%"  "40%"  "50%"  "30%"  "40%"  "30%"  "40%"  "50%"  "40%"  "30%"  "50%"  "10%"  "30%"  "50%"  "40%" 
>  [55] "20%"  "40%"  "40%"  "50%"  "20%"  "60%"  "60%"  "10%"  "30%"  "0"    "30%"  "50%"  "30%"  "40%"  "10%"  "40%"  "20%"  "70%" 
>  [73] "0"    "50%"  "10%"  "40%"  "30%"  "10%"  "30%"  "50%"  "70%"  "40%"  "20%"  "40%"  "20%"  "70%"  "30%"  "30%"  "20%"  "70%" 
>  [91] "20%"  "70%"  "20%"  "20%"  "20%"  "40%"  "30%"  "10%"  "30%"  "50%"
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, i just replaced the operator command to match my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to have a named `b` vector based on 'a', use the `match`

```
names(b) <- names(a)[match(b, a)]
names(b)
#[1] "20%"  "40%"  "40%"  "40%"  "60%"  "50%"  NA     "20%"  "50%"  "40%"  "50%"  "40%"  "30%"  "70%"  "30%" 
#[16] "60%"  "30%"  "30%"  "20%"  "20%"  "30%"  "30%"  "20%"  "10%"  "20%"  "60%"  "40%"  "70%"  "60%"  "10%" 
#[31] "40%"  "30%"  "30%"  "40%"  "20%"  "50%"  "20%"  "30%"  "100%" "60%"  "40%"  "50%"  "30%"  "40%"  "30%" 
#[46] "40%"  "50%"  "40%"  "30%"  "50%"  "10%"  "30%"  "50%"  "40%"  "20%"  "40%"  "40%"  "50%"  "20%"  "60%" 
#[61] "60%"  "10%"  "30%"  NA     "30%"  "50%"  "30%"  "40%"  "10%"  "40%"  "20%"  "70%"  NA     "50%"  "10%" 
#[76] "40%"  "30%"  "10%"  "30%"  "50%"  "70%"  "40%"  "20%"  "40%"  "20%"  "70%"  "30%"  "30%"  "20%"  "70%" 
#[91] "20%"  "70%"  "20%"  "20%"  "20%"  "40%"  "30%"  "10%"  "30%"  "50%"
```

Note that there are elements in 'b' that are not in 'a'.  It is not clear what should be the `names` for that elements.  By default, the `match` returns NA for those elements and the names for that elements will be `NA`.  If we need to change that, we could do it

Comment: This worked when I consider the vector b as discrete numbers. I apologize that I didn't write the question well on first post. Thank you!

Comment: @FoxyReign If you want to use `<=`, then `names(b) <- names(a)[ findInterval(b, a)]`